# Android change language in app only: Some strings not translated properly

Tags: java, android, string, android-fragments, localization

**(I've added an update on the bottom of the post)**

I am currently working on a project that will support multiple language. I have written all strings for all languages.

I use BaseActivity, Application class, and LocaleHelper to manage the localization on my app. 
And then I found this behavior on my app. After I setLocale to another language, Strings in some activities are changed and correct, but NOT in MainActivity even though they have some same strings. I tried to restart app and it's still not working.

I also have another activity which some of the words in activity got translated but all words inside a fragment and a recyclerview didn't get translated at all.

I still couldn't find why it's not translated properly. Can someone help me??

Here's some snippet:

**Application class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LocaleUtil.setLocale(new Locale(LocaleUtil.with(this).getPreference()));
    LocaleUtil.updateConfig(this,getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LocaleUtil.setLocale(new Locale(LocaleUtil.with(this).getPreference()));
    LocaleUtil.updateConfig(this, newConfig);
}
```

**BaseActivity**

```
public BaseActivity() {
    LocaleUtil.updateConfig(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initLocale();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void initLocale(){
    localeUtil = new LocaleUtil(this);
    localeUtil.setListener(this);
    localeUtil.setLanguageByCode(localeUtil.getPreference());
}
```

Please help me! THanks!!

(**UPDATE**)

I found out that I have to setLocale again whenever I want to access **Strings.xml** for any views in a recyclerview and a fragment. This is totally inconvenient and I'm worried about the performance. I would love to hear a better advice to change language.

Comment: You really aren't meant to directly change the locale like that.  It mostly works, but the way the system is meant to work is for you to follow the system locale and never change it yourself.  If you want to change it yourself you're almost better off writing your own system of strings.

Comment: Hello there! Sorry maybe I write wrong title. what I mean is that I have this "change language" setting on my app, I need to change language only on app. Can you explain more or give reference about how to write our "own system of strings"? Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. Maybe some string is not include.
From documentation.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework

> Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose
>   also that you want to localize all the text in your application to
>   French, and most of the text in your application (everything except
>   the application's title) to Japanese. In this case, you could create
>   three alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific
>   resource directory:
>
> res/values/strings.xml Contains English text for all the strings that
>   the application uses, including text for a string named title.
>   res/values-fr/strings.xml Contain French text for all the strings,
>   including title. res/values-ja/strings.xml Contain Japanese text for
>   all the strings except title. If your Java code refers to
>   R.string.title, here is what will happen at runtime:
>
> If the device is set to any language other than French, Android will
>   load title from the res/values/strings.xml file. If the device is set
>   to French, Android will load title from the res/values-fr/strings.xml
>   file. Notice that if the device is set to Japanese, Android will look
>   for title in the res/values-ja/strings.xml file. But because no such
>   string is included in that file, Android **will fall back to the
>   default**, and will load title in English from the
>   res/values/strings.xml file.

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. The language changes in Activities but doesn't change in Fragments. I tried it on more than one device, all had the same result. Later, I figured out a solution and it does work for me.

Solution:
Inside the Android Studio, go to the "Build" tab, select "Clean Project". Wait until it finished. (A loading bar is placed at the bottom right corner indicating the progress rate)
Next, go to the "Build" tab again, select "Rebuild Project". When it finished rebuilding, the problem should be solved.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, what I did is I set text from Java/Kotlin instead of XML.
I did this for headings as well though in my case headings are not changing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).